# HTML bash src attribute regex replacement

Tags: html, regex, bash

I need to write a bash script that does the following:

1. copies an html file

   - task: `cp index.html index2.html`
2. replaces certain characters i.e. `src="videos/` found inside of `index2.html` with new characters i.e. `src="content://com.company.app/videos/`

   - task: replace `src="videos/` with `src="content://com.company.app/videos/` inside of `index2.html`

As you can see, I can do step one. However, I need help doing step 2. What should I write in the bash script?

Comment: [Obligatory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) (You'll find things easier if you do the HTML editing in Perl/Python/JavaScript/etc after finding a decent DOM library).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -ri 's~(src=")(videos\/)~\1content\://com.company.app/\2~' index2.html
```

With sed you can enable regular expressions with -r and enable changes to index2.html with -i. Then we split src=" by surrounding it with brackets and do the same with videos\ We then refer to these as \1 and \2 adding the additional text. s signifies the sed substitute mode and so s~text in file~text to change to~

Comment: Thanks @RamanSailopal - this works perfectly - 

I had to use `gsed` instead of `sed` to get the -r flag to work on my machine. But it worked great! Thanks.